# How to create such query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have four  tables:

- tournaments (id, name, slots, price, gameId, platformId)
- games (id, name)
- platforms (id, name)
- participations (id, tournamentId, playerId)

I want to get tournament's game name, platform name, slots, price, reservedSlots (participations count), information whether some player (his id is provided by php) participate in this tournament (bool/true) and conditions are:
- gameId must be in specified array provided by php
- platformId must be in specified array provided by php

I have created something like this but it doesn't work correctly:

php:

```
$platformsList = "'". implode("', '", $platforms) ."'"; // 
$gamesList = "'". implode("', '", $games). "'";
```

mysql:

```
    SELECT
    t. NAME AS tournamentName,
    t.id,
    t.slots,
    p. NAME,
    g. NAME AS gameName,
    t.price
FROM
    tournaments AS t,
    platforms AS p,
    games AS g,
    participations AS part
WHERE
    t.PlatformId = p.Id
AND t.GameId = g.Id
AND t.Slots - (
    SELECT
        count(*)
    FROM
        participations
    WHERE
        TournamentId = t.id
) > 0
AND part.TournamentId = t.Id
AND t.PlatformId IN ($platformsList)
AND t.GameId IN ($gamesList)
```

Comment: what doesn't work? error log? does the query work in mysql workbench, i.e is the query valid

Comment: And what is exactly wrong? You get no output, or wrong output?

Comment: There is output but it isn't what I want. It returns as many records as participations with given arguments exists

Comment: Ok i forgot to add GROUP BY t.Name so I i think now I have correct tournaments list, but still i don't have

- reservedSlots (participations count)

- information whether some player (his id is provided by php) participate in this tournament (false/true)

Answer (score 1):

I will not dwelve into handling your post and get values, I will assume that everything is all right:

```
$possibleGameIDs = getPossibleGameIDs(); //function will return the array you need for possible game id values. Inside your function make sure that the id values are really numeric
$possiblePlatformIDs = getPossiblePlatformIDs(); //function will return the array you need for possible platform id values. Inside your function make sure that the id values are really numeric
$playerId = getPlayerId(); //function returns the player id and makes sure that it is really a number

$sql = "select games.name, platforms.name, tournaments.slots, tournaments.price, ".
       "(select count(*) from participations where participations.tournamentId = tournaments.tournamentId) as reservedSlots, ".
       "(select count(*) > 0 from participations where participations.tournamentId = tournaments.tournamentId and playerId = ".$playerId.") as isParticipating ".
       "from tournamens ".
       "join games ".
       "on tournaments.gameId = games.id ".
       "join platforms ".
       "on tournaments.platformId = platforms.id ".
       "where games.id in (".implode(",", $possibleGameIDs).") and ".
       "      platforms.id in (".implode(",", $possiblePlatformIDs).") and ".
       "      tournaments.slots > 0"
```

Code was not tested, so please, let me know if you experience any problems using it. Naturally you need to run it, but as you did not specify what do you use to run the query, I did not allocate time to deal with technical details of running it. Beware SQL injections though.

Comment: I think that is what I was looking for ;) I only added one condition to get only open tournaments, but thank you was answer, problem solved.

Comment: @Lukas, I am glad I could help. If my answer solved the problem, then you may consider accepting it as the correct answer.